# Which Mac program is it on the image used for basic coding?

Tags: php

Which Mac program is it on the image used for basic coding?

From the video of Code Igniter:

[image]

Comment: Looks like an old version of Coda. Although I could be mistaken.

Comment: I Believe its an inbuilt code editor for the MAC OSX

Answer (score 1):

That's TextMate @ http://macromates.com/ and it's quite decent once you get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Textmate](http://macromates.com/) to me.